# Android: Is it possible to hide the top part of the actionbar but keep the bottom bar with the overflow buttons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

currently i am using ActionbarSherlock.

Right now, my apps has a Bar at top and a bar at the bottom with overflowed buttons.

I want a custom header bar and do not want to try to theme the Actionbar header bar, but I want to keep the bottom bar with the buttons.

Is it possible to hide the Header bar portion of the ActionBar?

ActionBar().hide() hides both top and bottom bars.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `.setVisibility(View.GONE)`?

Comment: .setVisibility(View.GONE) on what?

Comment: Write your own theme which has no top bar?

Comment: @AlexCheuk Try `findViewById(R.id.nameoftheview).setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: I dont think you can actually do this. The ActionBar is designed to stay on top and provide the various features & affordances that it does. It splits when there are too many items to fit on top.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the action bar doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) ("Using split action bar"): add uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" to the corresponding  manifest element. Then use setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false). The tabs move are moved into the - now empty - top bar.